# AHK keystroke to show image only while it's pressed

Tags: image, autohotkey, getstate

Good day,

I'm trying to create a script for AutoHotKey (AHK) which will show an image when having pressed **Caps lock**+**A** simultaneously and will hide after releasing the keys.

My current solution shows the image, but it only will go away after pressing **Esc**:

```
#Persistent
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
#If, GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P")

a::
Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Theme -Border -Caption
Gui, Color, FFFFFF
WinSet, Transcolor, FFFFFF
Gui, Add, Picture, x0 y0 w1827 h635, C:\Users\User\Image.png
Gui, Show, xCenter y360 w1827 h635
Gui, Margin, 0,0
return
GuiEscape: 
Gui, Cancel
Gui, Hide
return
```

I've experimented with setting a **state** or **a UP::** but nothing worked. Looking forward to some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[KeyWait](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm) seems to be what you are looking for.

From the docs:

> ### KeyWait
>
> Waits for a key or mouse/joystick button to be released or pressed
> down.
>
> ```
> KeyWait, KeyName , Options
> ```

So in order to delay the script until the <kbd>a</kbd> key to be released, you would implement it as so:

```
KeyWait a
```

---

Final Code:

```
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
#If, GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P")

a::
Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Theme -Border -Caption
Gui, Color, FFFFFF
WinSet, Transcolor, FFFFFF
Gui, Add, Picture, x0 y0 w1827 h635, C:\Users\User\Image.png
Gui, Show, xCenter y360 w1827 h635
Gui, Margin, 0,0
KeyWait a
gosub GuiEscape
return

GuiEscape: 
Gui, Cancel
Gui, Hide
return
```

Comment: Fantastic! I does exactly what I desired. I haven't found anything about KeyWait in correlation with such a solution so I think this post might be useful to others in the future. Thank you!